# TableViewCell ImageView shows always different data

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a chat and want to display the users profile pictures.
Everything will be displayed correctly but not the profile pictures of the users. 
Everytime, when I reload my view, I get other pictures.

I load the Profileimage in with the following lines:

```
func showProfilImage(uid: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
    UserApi.shared.observeUser(uid: uid) { (user) in
        guard let url = URL(string: user.profilImageUrl!) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil, let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let finishedImage = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                    completion(finishedImage)
                }
                }.resume()
    }
}
```

Then I call `showProfilImage` in `cellForRowAt` with the following lines:

```
self.showProfilImage(uid: self.items[indexPath.row].user.uid!) { (image) in
    cell.profilePic.image = image
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now i implemented sdWebImage and make a completion with the URL:

```
func showProfilImage(uid: String, completion: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
    UserApi.shared.observeUser(uid: uid) { (user) in
        guard let url = URL(string: user.profilImageUrl!) else { return }
        completion(url)
    }
}
```

Here I call my `showProfilImage`:

```
self.showProfilImage(uid: self.items[indexPath.row].user.uid!) { (url) in
            cell.profilePic.image = nil
            cell.profilePic.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: { (_, _, _, _) in
            })
        }
```

Comment: Don't load the (same) pictures a zillion times in `cellForRow`, load it **once** per user when populating the data source in the controller or in the model. At least use something to cache the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code has dequeuing and no cashing problems and the right for that is to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

```
cell.profilePic.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:urlStr), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

also something like

```
UserApi.shared.observeUser(uid: uid) { (user) in
```

would be once say in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: updated my question. I now implemented sdWebImage but still the same problem. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: i guess `observeUser` is called many times and the user profile is changed also ?

Comment: I call observeUser only once in the code. It will be called for every tableViewCell (this time I have 4 users/conversations). So it will be called 4 times. Right?

Comment: it will be called 4 times , and when you scroll the one that hides and reshown will be called again , consider doing all of this once by starting a background calls to all the images when the vc is shown may be in `viewDidLoad` then refresh the table

Comment: no need of the showProfilImage anymore. Just call that line of code: 
`let imageUrl = URL(string: self.items[indexPath.row].user.profilImageUrl!)
            cell.profilePic.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl) { (_, _, _, _) in
            }`
in items, I have all the users, so I don't need to load them a second time. 
No problems with this code!

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching the image correctly for each user 
then you problem might be laying in scrolling and dequeuing the cell 
to solve such issue inside the `UITableViewCell` custom class use this function to clear out the `UIImageView` each time a dequeue happens.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.imageView.image = nil  //setting the image to nil  when get dequeued to reuse 
    }
```

Read more about this function [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)

Answer (score -1):

UITableView reuses its views that means when you load an image one time and cell goes out of screen UITableView will bring the cell back to screen for different data source but the image that previously loaded will still presented on the UIImageView 
add this line of code

```
cell.profilePic.image = nil
self.showProfilImage(uid: self.items[indexPath.row].user.uid!) { (image) in
        cell.profilePic.image = image
    }
```